# Formatting code in posts on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request

I found that " code sample " sometimes doesn't work as I want it to.
See my question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352029/tabbar-didselect-item-manage-dynamically-iphone

I tried to edit & correct code format But I wasn't able to format it.
The code was directly copied from Xcode. Yet not formatted properly.

So:

- could you please show me the way to format my code properly?
- or, similar to the way image insertion has different screen, Stack Overflow should have some different mechanism to enter code only. (I am just suggesting for the feature.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be recognized as code, each line of it has to be indented by 4 spaces. You can achieve this either by inserting the spaces by hand, or by selecting the code block and clicking the "101010" button of the editor (keyboard shortcut is Ctrl-K).

I have done exactly that (Ctrl-K) with your question.

Comment: What is the short cut of mac keyboard?

Comment: @sugar - `CMD-K`

Answer (score 0):

I think it already got fixed. The problem with the original version is **all** code lines must be indented (4 spaces), and must be separated by at least one line from non-code.

```
Like so
```

So to illustrate pretending I'm in the editor...

```
this is my regular text

    this is my code
    and more code
```

but not ("must be separated by at least one line from non-code")

```
this is my regular text
    this is my code
    and more code
```

or ("**all** code lines must be indented")

```
this is my regular text

    this is my code
and more code
```

Comment: The original code was indented and separated fine; however it was indented with tabs instead of spaces.